# 3g connection no call control when navigate between views angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, 3g

I 'm creating a mobile application using angularjs and Ionic .

One of the parts of the application is to create a list of items by calling a REST API. If I am testing the application from the desktop computer or from your mobile using WIFI , everything works perfectly and the list refreshes .

However, if the mobile prove to do the same using 3G connection, the drivers are not called when I navigate between views, and so the list is not refreshed , showing the previous value.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If you could post your code, it would help solving the problem quickly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264677/refresh-scope-and-list-of-items-slow-connections